# How does displaying/hiding prices impact conversion?

Tags: information-architecture, conversion, pricing

So I am retooling a page for a company that offers tiered pricing packages based on the number of users for our software. Small business = $x/mo kind of thing.

**Does anyone have any conversion data or links or any kind of evidence of the conversion and impact of actually listing prices on a the site versus just showing the packages without listing the price?**

I have managed to find a ton of articles on how people *like* prices listed, or simply saying it is a *good idea* but none of them seem to offer any kind of real evidence other than opinion.

Comment: Sorry you didn't get a decent response on this. I think the reason is, conversion rates vary radically depending on the product,  presentation and many other variables. So no there is not a canonical answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of articles here:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.919.9957&rep=rep1&type=pdf

http://www.acrwebsite.org/search/view-conference-proceedings.aspx?Id=11963

I think showing price in the beginning set the expectation right otherwise you may see a lot of drop-off at later stage. It may not need to be on your face but after highlighting features of product or service.

We are in an interesting discussion at work whether to introduce point system instead of showing monetary value. Soon we will go through some usability research then I will feedback.

Comment: If you can add some of the relevant content from the articles. (Link rot)

Answer (score 0):

I've often wondered the same thing, but was unable to come up with a definitive answer.

Although it's just one article, this company doubled their conversion rate by hiding pricing: http://krispetersen.com/2013/09/the-effect-of-hiding-prices-on-service-based-marketplace-conversion-rates/

Comment: That is perfect!!!